# How to achieve desired JSON format using C#.NET HashTable

Tags: c#, hashtable

How to achieve below mentioned JSON format using C#.NET HashTable

```
{"DoWorkResult":
      [
       {"Perimeter":"55},
       {"Mortgage":"540"},
       {"Area":"1000"}
      ]
}
```

I tried to do this with Hashtable with an example as like below

```
    Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable();

    hashtable.Add("Area", 1000);
    hashtable.Add("Perimeter", 55);
    hashtable.Add("Mortgage", 540);
```

But the result is as shown below

```
{"DoWorkResult":
      [
       {"Key":"Perimeter","Value":55},
       {"Key":"Mortgage","Value":540},
       {"Key":"Area","Value":1000}
      ]
}
```

**Note :** I am returning the actual Hash table in a WCF service method, and i am using an ajax call to read the output from backend.

**Ajax Method i am using in front end :**

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Service.svc/DoWork',
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
```

Comment: What are you using to convert to JSON? Did you try [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/), as it might yield a better result?

Comment: Why can't you use `Dictionary` instead of `HashTable`?

Comment: @SergRogovtsev : I am new to C#, sure i can try using Dictionary..

Comment: @JensenSomers As i am using a webservice method, i have mentioned `ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json` in my Interface.
I have updated the ajax call i am using in the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using both [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) and [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

```
var list = new ArrayList();
list.Add(new { Area = 1000 });
list.Add(new { Perimeter = 55 });
list.Add(new { Mortgage = 540 });

var s1 = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new { DoWorkResult = list });
var s2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { DoWorkResult = list });
```

Comment: +1 - but use List<object> instead of ArrayList. They should deprecate that class altogeteher